# ReactJs app with a static page outside the routing

Tags: reactjs, apache, authentication

I have a ReactJs web application, running on an Apache server.

The Authentication is done using Client Certificate, therefore when the user lands on *[www.mydomain.com/my-app](http://www.mydomain.com/my-app)* Apache will ask for a Client Certificate authentication.

Now I need to provide a public page to the users, that can be viewed by anyone, like the following:

```
www.mydomain.com/my-app/the-public-page
or it can be also
www.mydomain.com/my-app/the-public-page.html
```

Is there a way to configure Apache and/or React in order to bypass the routing that redirects the requests to the root path and therefore triggers the authentication on the Client Certificate?